# Extract name from string with Tika not working

Tags: java, apache-tika

I have this code and I am trying to extract name from a String using Tika Apache, but the names field is returned as an empty array and I can't figure it out why.

Here is the code, thanks!

```
public static List<String> extractDataFromText(@NonNull String input) throws TikaException, IOException, SAXException {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));;
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    try {
        parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
    } catch (TikaException | SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] personValues = metadata.getValues("person");
    if (personValues != null) {
        Collections.addAll(names, personValues);
    }

    System.out.println(names);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_ADDRESS + "|" + PHONE_NUMBER);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        data.add(matcher.group());
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Can you show some `input` data and the expected `names` output?

Comment: Yes, the data is a resume that I am parsing in another method and store the content as a string (that content is passed in this method as input) that contains the following information ,,Sam Sam

xxxxxx@gmail.com            

07xxxxxxxx"

I expect to receive the name Sam Sam or something like that, I want to retrive the username from that string.

Comment: So the input is a string that contains the words ,,Sam Sam" along side a phone number and an email address and the expected output should be ,,Sam Sam".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide actual data samples there. (Tika expects to find a parseable data structure  not just a free-format text file.) Can you provide a MRE?